# Minecraft 1.10.2 Mob drops

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a Spider drop only certain items without the normal drops of string and eyes but nothing I do works. I've tried unluck effects and changing gamerules (like entitydrop and mobloot) but I still get the normal drops. This is the command I'm using.

```
/summon Spider ~ ~1 ~ {HandDropChances:[0.5F,2F],HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:skull",Damage:1,tag:{display:{Name:Bomb}},Count:1},{}],ArmorDropChances:[0.5F,0.5F,2F,2F],ArmorItems:[{id:"minecraft:nether_wart",tag:{display:{Name:Heart}},Count:1},{id:"minecraft:emerald",Count:1},{},{}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the normal drops, you can give the spider a `DeathLootTable` of `"minecraft:empty"`.

```
/summon Spider ~ ~1 ~ {DeathLootTable:"minecraft:empty",HandDropChances:[0.5F,2F],HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:skull",Damage:1,tag:{display:{Name:Bomb}},Count:1},{}],ArmorDropChances:[0.5F,0.5F,2F,2F],ArmorItems:[{id:"minecraft:nether_wart",tag:{display:{Name:Heart}},Count:1},{id:"minecraft:emerald",Count:1},{},{}]}
```